# Invertible Functions

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

In some mathematics texts, a function is invertible iff the function is one-to-one and onto. However, in some calculus texts (thomas's calculus, stewart's calculus, etc.), the only requirement for a function to be invertible is one-to-one. Why in those calculus texts the only requirement for a function to be invertible is one-to-one while in some other mathematics texts the requirements for a function to be invertible are one-to-one and onto?

Answer (score 3):

A function is always onto its image; thus, if we have a function $f:X\to Y$ that is $1-1$, we could have $f^{-1}:f(X)\to X$.

This may be where the discrepancy between the definition lies.